# What's wrong with my codes/

Tags: arduino-uno

My teacher gave us a performance output about doing a dancing christmas lights in tinkercad. But I don't know what to do about the codes. He left  an instruction to us about what to do. I follow it but the tinkercad keep telling that...

```
Sorry, it seems like your code has some errors.
Close
 In function 'void setup()':
13:5: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
21:7: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
41:61: error: expected '}' at end of input
41:61: error: expected '}' at end of input
41:61: error: expected '}' at end of input
 exit status 1
```

**And here's the code that I've entered...**

```
int ledPins[]={3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
void setup()
{
  for(int i =0; i <11; i++)
  {
    pinMode(ledPins[i],OUTPUT);
}
  {
  void setup()
    {
     for (int i=0; i <11; i++)
     {
       pinMode(ledPins[i],OUTPUT);
     }
  }
    {
      void loop()
      {
        int i = 0;
        while (i<10)
          
        {
          {
            digitalWrite(ledPins{i],HIGH);
            delay(100);
            digitalWrite(ledPins[i],LOW);
            i++;
                                }
                         }
                         i = 10;
                         while (i >0
                                {
                                  digitalWrite(ledPins[i],HIGH;
                                               delay(100);
                                               digitalWrite(ledPins[i],LOW;
                                                            i--;
                                                            }
                                                            }
```

And here's the instruction of my teaher for the codes...

6. Initialize variables
Use array to initialize variables.
Set ledPin as the name of the variable and initialize the Arduino pins that you’re going to use.
Never forget to end each statement with semicolon

7. Set all pin to output
Use function void setup ()
Create a for () loop for array manipulation.
Initialize the for loop with i=0; since we will start the dancing lights with all LEDs turned off.
Initialize the condition i<11; since we need to turn on the 10 LEDs.

Set the increment to i++ because we need to iterate until it reaches the last LED.
Configure pin using pinMode().
Place a curly bracket before and after the for loop and pinMode().
8. Create a loop
Use function void loop().
Create a variable, i = 0.
Use while() for continuous looping
First while() is used to run your light from right to left.

Second while() is used to run your light from left to right. 
Place a curly bracket before and after your statement block
Never forget to end each statement with semicolon

Comment: You seem to have brackets-tourettes. You really need to look at those brackets. Examine the shape of them, and the order of them. Hint: for every opening { there must be a closing }. For every opening ( there must be a closing ). For every opening [ there must be a closing ].

Comment: Are those the only codes that I need to change?

Comment: I don't know. Your code is such a mess I have no clue what it's intending to do.

Comment: You need to get the brackets right. Though that is not about Arduino, thus off topic here. You can search for C/C++ tutorials on the web to get the syntax right. Also you should use an autoformatting function (don't know, if Tinkercad has one, but the Arduino IDE has it) to get the indenting right. Otherwise you have to do it manually. Once the code is correctly indented, it is way easier to see the bracket problems.

Comment: you really need to look at the example code in the Arduino IDE ... see how the code is formatted, which means how it is indented ... indent levels are like paragraphs in writing ... your code has indentation, but it is all over the place without reason

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's wrong with my codes?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/77967/whats-wrong-with-my-codes)

Comment: Duplicate of [https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/77967/whats-wrong-with-my-codes](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/77967/whats-wrong-with-my-codes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed it, so it at least compiles.

```
int ledPins[]={3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
void setup()
{
  for(int i=0; i < 11; i++)
  {
    pinMode(ledPins[i],OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop()
{
  int i = 0;
  while (i < 10)
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPins[i],HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(ledPins[i],LOW);
    i++;
  }
  i = 10;
  while (i > 0)
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPins[i],HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(ledPins[i],LOW);
    i--;
  }
}
```